# How to handle exceptions in ethreum private network using revert(),throw

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, geth-debugging

I am running a private ethereum network using

```
 geth  --rpc  --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ./chaindata --port "30330" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,th,net,web3" --networkid 2010 init genesis.json
```

and then

```
geth  --rpc  --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ./chaindata --port "30330" --gasprice 1 --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 2010 console
```

when I calls a contract functions

```
 function checkValid( string Name)public returns(bool)
{
    if(isvaliduser[Name]==false)revert();
    Count[Name]+=1;        
 }
```

Which is deployed in remix solidity IDE, in web3 provider environment, I have given wrong parameters in order to call revert .The functions does not get executed and stays in transaction pending.

But my problem is : Now after giving correct parameters also function do not execute, what can be the reason.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A `revert` operation should not cause the transaction to remain in the pending state. The transaction should be processed, and included in the blockchain, but have no effect except for incrementing the sender account's nonce and spending any gas that was used up the point where the contract hit `revert`.

If your transactions are really getting stuck in a pending state, don't worry the content of your contract and instead look at some of these issues to see which matches what you're seeing:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=transaction+stuck+pending